# Javascript tutorial confusion about variable

Tags: javascript, variables

Im reading the tutorials [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_fornext_header).

I am getting confused trying to understand some of this example, why is the variable declared as nothing and what does the ,i indicate

```
var x="",i;
```

and also why do you use

```
 x=x
```

at the beginning of the line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to loop from 1 to 6, to make HTML headings.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x="",i;
for (i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
 x=x + "<h" + i + ">Heading " + i + "</h" + i + ">";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***NEVER NEVER NEVER*** use w3schools. http://w3fools.com

Comment: Try [CodeAcademy](http://www.codeacademy.com) instead, I just finished their Javascript track, it isn't too bad.

Comment: `x = x + i;` means take the current value of `x`, append `i` to it, then assign that back to `x`. It's building the string up during the loop.

Comment: Oh that's a bumber they seem to have a large collection of knowledge that I was excited to go through. Do you have any recommendations on simulare sites with more creditable information that I can learn from?

Comment: Oh thank you Evan that clears that up.

Comment: I always recommend the book *Object-Oriented JavaScript* by Stoyan Stefanov, it does a great job of teaching modern JavaScript. [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is a pretty good, free book. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is also a great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var x="",i;

This translates as

```
var x = "";
var i;
```

which simply declares those variables within the current scope.

> x=x + ...

This means replace the value of `x` with the value of the expression to the right of the `=` sign. In this case, you are concatenating a string to the end of the current value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x="",i;
```

is the same as

```
var x = "";
var i;
```

Declare variables in the form of

```
var a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3;
```

is common and make the code style looking clear and easy to read.

Comment: So whats the differance between

      var x;
and 

      var x="";

Comment: **var x = ""** make **x** an empty string, then x is now really containing somthing, while **var x** will just declare the existence of **x** and the **x** now is undefined and it is ready to be set value for x later

Comment: It's always a good habit in JS to use **var** to declare an variable first no matter by **var x** or **var x = 'blabla'**, otherwise, **x** will become global and that is not a good pattern in JS

Comment: If you want to start learning javascript, the book [javascript definitive guide](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596000480) is something you can start with. This is the best javascript book to start.